# What happened to priests in Germany during the Protestant Reformation and the wars of religion?

Tags: religion, germany, protestantism

I'm curious to know what happened to them as Protestantism spread.

I've researched a little in the Catholicism in Germany Wikipedia page's section on the Reformation. (Couldn't find anything there.) I got curious because I have some vague idea about what happened in England, but little idea about the protestant (and protestant ruled) parts of Germany.

Comment: Please show us what you have discovered so far. Presumably you mean Catholic priests...? Where have you looked?

Comment: A little in the Catholicism in Germany wikipedia page's section on the reformation. (Couldn't find anything there.)
I got curious because I have some vague idea about what happened in England, but little idea about the protestant (and protestant ruled) parts of Germany.

Comment: @StepStart Please update the question instead of responding to comments. Thank you

Comment: Many Catholic priests converted to the Protestant cause, especially urban priests. Many of these had been influenced by the recent philosophy of Humanism, an important cultural trend among the educated during the preceding 30 years.  Read any good history of the Reformation.